# Reversing colum names, but not column position

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where the columns are named from from 11 to 0. I want the numbers reversed, but only for the column names, the data in the columns should remain the same position.

I have looked into [`rename`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rename.html). I could rename the columns one by one, but I need a flexible solution as the numbers of columns will change and I will end up with a rather large number of rows.

I have also considered resetting the index, but that seems to only work on rows.

Example:

```
   11  10  9  8 ... 0
0   A   B  C  D ... L
1   A   B  C  D ... L
2   A   B  C  D ... L
```

What I would like it to look like:

```
    0   1  2  3 ... 11
0   A   B  C  D ... L
1   A   B  C  D ... L
2   A   B  C  D ... L
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can just reverse by:

```
df.columns = df.columns[::-1]
```

Comment: That simple. Thanks!